# Probability that a random reduced fraction has an odd denominator

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution, monte-carlo

Suppose you choose a rational number at random and reduce it; what is the probability that the denominator is odd?

I looked around and heard you can't define a uniform probability measure on the rationals so the question is useless, but I ran some monte carlo simulations and no matter what bounds I chose, I always saw $\frac{2}{3}$ as the answer.

This makes me think that the question is well defined, but I'm not sure, because the question of the probability of choosing two random integers such that they are coprime does have a well defined answer, $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

An formulation that I think is equivalent is:

Let $A,B \sim U(1,n)$ be discrete random variables, then consider the new random variable $X = \frac{A}{\gcd(A,B)} \pmod{2}$, then what is $\mathbb{P}(X = 1)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Of the numbers, $A$ and $B$... we ask how many times $2$ is a factor of each.  Clearly, the probability that $A$ has more factors of $2$ than $B$ has is going to be equal to the probability that $B$ has more factors of $2$ than $A$ has.  So, the question becomes what is the probability they have the same number of factors of $2$.  Them both being odd, them both being odd multiples of $2$, them both being odd multiples of $4$, etc...  $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{64}+\dots=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: So, a third of the time they have the same, half of what remains which becomes a third of the time $B$ has more, and similarly a third of the time $A$ has more.  Your probability then is the sum of the case of it being the same and $B$ having more, for a total of $\frac{2}{3}$